# Windows Live Mail Export to Exchange

Tags: exchange, export, windows-live-mail

When I export to Exchange from Windows Live Mail, what file does it create and in which directory?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting to Exchange creates a .pst file under:
C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\

Assuming you have MS Outlook installed.

This file can be directly opened by Outlook using File>Open>Outlook Data File

Comment: Actually pst file's aren't stored in the roaming profile, should be C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\

Comment: It doesn't seem to create any pst file there (neither in Local nor in roaming profile. Where else should i look into?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I already had Outlook set up, and I was trying to import EML files that I had exported from Mozilla (Thunderbird/Seamonkey). On none of the pages I have been reading to do this operation does it say where it puts the files! Unreal.

It turns out it puts the exported folders directly in the default Outlook PST file. I thought it would create a new PST file (which, frankly, makes more sense) but alas it dumps it into the existing PST file (the default one; I have many). Be careful of same-named folders - I don't know what it would do. Merge them? That would be bad.

So open Outlook and look for the folder name(s) of the folder(s) you imported. If you don't have Outlook already installed, I don't know where it goes. The default location of the Outlook (2007) pst file is as mentioned above: C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst. Perhaps it would be put there in that case?

I am using Outlook 2007 and Windows Live Mail 2011 on Windows 7 .

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need do is open your Outlook client on the same computer as the Windows Live mail program you used to export from and look in the folder list for 'Imported Folder' and drill down.

Then you can perform an export to a .pst if you need to backup the file of move it to another machine. Windows Live mail does not create the .pst for you but it migrates it to Outlook so you can from there.

So the steps are :

Export your .dbx from older outlook client - 
Import it into Windows live mail - 
Export it as an Exchange/Outlook file - 
Open outlook and export as a .pst (if need be, depends if you have use for the file on another computer)